# cant access browser for neo4j db set up on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, neo4j, virtual-machine, graph-databases

I get the This site can’t be reached error on chrome when i do https://[EXTERNAL_IP]:7473/browser and put in the actual external ip for the neo4j database. The google VM has a firewall and Ive permitted traffic on http and https, but Im still getting the error.